# WPF MediaElement - image won't update when video is Paused and Position is reset

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mediaelement

I am using a WPF MediaElement to play a video.  While the MediaElement is Paused, I set the Position to another point in the video. I would like the video image in the MediaElement to refresh to reflect the new position. But it will not update the image until I push the Play button again. Is there a way to force an MediaElement image refresh without calling its Play method?

Code example

```
TimeSpan tsPosition = new TimeSpan(0,0,30);   // set to 30 seconds
MediaElementObj.Position = tsPosition;
 if (PlayStatus == PAUSED) // ignore if not paused
            {
                // image refresh method call here if there is a way to do it
            }
```

Comment: Do you have any xaml you can show us?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the [ScrubbingEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.scrubbingenabled.aspx) Property on the MediaElement to true.